# Sampling 2 balls of the same colour probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, sampling-theory

A bag has 3 red, 3 blue and 3 green balls. 2 balls are picked at random without replacement. What is the probability that they are of the same colour?

I am thinking what is the easiest way to do this using sampling? The sample space has $72$ outcomes (ordered without replacement). Then for 1st ball, we have ${9}\choose{1}$ choices; since we want 2nd ball same colour as 1st, we need to use ${2}\choose{1}$, and hence we have the probability to be $\frac{9 \times 2}{72} = \frac{1}{4}$.

Is this the fastest way using ordered sampling?

Comment: More simply:  Whichever you choose first, for the second there are $2$ winning choices out of $8$, hence the answer is $\frac 28=\frac 14$.

Comment: The fastest and right way is $3\cdot \frac{\binom{3}{2}\cdot\binom{3}{0}\cdot\binom{3}{0}  }{\binom{9}{2} }$

Comment: I understand ${3}\choose{2}$ means you pick $2$ balls out of $3$ of the same colour, and then factor of $3$ at the front accounts for the fact you have $3$ colours, but can you explain why you have two ${3}\choose{0}$ terms? @callculus42

Comment: @Astral You choose 2 red balls, 0 blue balls  and 0 green balls.

Comment: Yes, but I assume strictly speaking these terms ${3}\choose{0}$ are redundant, since from context  of question ${3}\choose{2}$  already accounts that we chose $2$ balls? @callculus42

Comment: @Astral It is a more general approach. With it you can easily calculate the probability to choose 2 red balls, 1 blue ball and 1 green ball, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Also the next option can be:

$$
\frac{\binom{3}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{9}{2}}=\frac{1}{4}.
$$